# I cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas database even though my IP is whitelisted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to a mongoDB Atlas cluster using my node app, it wasn't working so I tried it with the mongoDB Compass. It shows timeout error. I can't figure out the problem, I have already whitelisted my IP from the database.

I am behind a proxy (my college has a proxy) but I even tried it with mobile data but it still won't work.

Comment: When you changed to mobile data, did you update the list of whitelisted IP on Atlas?

Comment: I actually had whitelisted all IPs